# Macro to replace undefined tokens with some predefined value

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Macro to replace undefined tokens with some predefined value.

I would like to have some EXPAND(x) macro that will expand to x if x is defined and to, for example, -1 if it is not, so that this code:

```
#define M1 1
#define M2 2
#undef  M3
#define M4 (2*2)

printf("%i %i %i %i", EXPAND(M1), EXPAND(M2), EXPAND(M3), EXPAND(M4));
```

would print:

```
1 2 -1 4
```

Is that possible in C? Only thing that I can think of is to stringify x and then parse it with constexpr function, but that will work only in simple cases.

Comment: There is nothing C++ specific in the question, so please tag it C only. I'll fix it.

Comment: *"but that will work only in simple cases"* Why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to use some header file that knows all possible macros and checks if they are defined. If not, replace them with -1.

```
#ifndef M1
#define M1 -1
#endif

#ifndef M2
#define M2 -1
#endif

...
```

You would then include this header after the file containing the macros/after the macro defines.

Though please note that this is a bad design, full of tight coupling and other incredibly bad ideas. There's certainly better ways to solve the actual problem, like ensuring that the code won't compile if a certain macro is missing.